# t-SNE perplexity for groups of different sizes

Tags: tsne

I have a data set of about 1200 samples that I expect to be divided in to about 40 groups but the group sizes vary from about 5 to 150 samples. About half of the groups have 10-40 samples, 10 have fewer than 10 samples and 1 group has over 100 samples. My understanding of perplexity is that it's related to the group sizes (number of neighbors). Using R (Rtsne) I tried using a perplexity of 5, 15, 30, and 50, they all have some good groups and a few that don't look quite right. How should I choose perplexity when the group sizes are so different? Or is t-SNE not appropriate for a data set with such variability in group sizes?